# Custom label for optidef

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, optidef

I have an optimization problem as follows

```
 \begin{mini}|l|
  {}{f(x)}{}{}
  \label{generalP1}
  \addConstraint{g_{j}(x)}{\le 0, j = 1, \hdots, m}
  \addConstraint{        x }{\in \mathcal{C}}
 \end{mini}
```

[image]
The label appears as (1) but I would like to change the label to my own labeling like say $\alpha$

I tried looking at `optidef` package's documentation but I couldn't find anything helpful. Any way how to tackle this?

Comment: [tag:labels] is **not** meant for the [tag:cross-referencing] labels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mini` environment is actually a wrapper for an `equation` and `alignat` environments. And as the `equation` environment, the starred version does not produce a number, and you can put a `\tag` instead.

This will do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini*}|l|
 {}{f(x)}{}{}
 \label{generalP1}
 \addConstraint{g_{j}(x)}{\le 0, j = 1, \hdots, m}\tag{$\alpha$}
 \addConstraint{        x }{\in \mathcal{C}}
\end{mini*}

\end{document}
```

[image]